Implementing elaboration in the Proust proof assistant
In section 2.6 of the tutorial "Logic and Computation Intertwined", the author states "We could keep type and possibly context information in the AST, a process commonly known as "elaboration"."
I have been translating the code from the tutorial into Lean and I'm wondering what that would look like. By the AST are they referring to the definition of lambda terms? If so, how would that change? Would there be separate code for just the process of elaboration? What would that look like?
import Lean

set_option autoImplicit false


-- https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~plragde/flaneries/LACI/index.html
-- https://github.com/fEst1ck/hsProust


open Lean Elab Meta


@[reducible]
def Symbol_ : Type := String
deriving Inhabited, DecidableEq, Repr


inductive Type_ : Type
| Var : Symbol_ → Type_
| Arrow : Type_ → Type_ → Type_
deriving Inhabited, DecidableEq, Repr

def Type_.toString : Type_ → String
| Type_.Var W => s! "{W}"
| Type_.Arrow T1 T2 => s! "({T1.toString} -> {T2.toString})"

instance : ToString Type_ :=
  { toString := fun (T : Type_) => T.toString }


def Context_ : Type := AssocList Symbol_ Type_
deriving Inhabited

def Context_.toString
  (Gamma : Context_) :
  String :=
  Gamma.toList.toString

instance : ToString Context_ :=
  { toString := fun (Gamma : Context_) => Gamma.toString }


structure Goal_ : Type :=
  (context : Context_)
  (type : Type_)
deriving Inhabited

def Goal_.toString
  (goal : Goal_) :
  String :=
  s! "{goal.context}\n{goal.type}"

instance : ToString Goal_ :=
  { toString := fun (goal : Goal_) => goal.toString }


inductive Term_ : Type
| Var : Symbol_ → Term_
| App : Term_ → Term_ → Term_
| Abs : Symbol_ → Term_ → Term_
| Ann : Term_ → Type_ → Term_
| Hole : Option Nat → Term_
deriving Inhabited, DecidableEq, Repr

def Term_.toString : Term_ → String
| Term_.Var x => s! "{x}"
| Term_.App e1 e2 => s! "({e1.toString} {e2.toString})"
| Term_.Abs x e => s! "(\\ {x} . {e.toString})"
| Term_.Ann e T => s! "({e.toString} : {T.toString})"
| Term_.Hole opt =>
  match opt with
  | Option.some n => s! "?{n}"
  | Option.none => "?"

instance : ToString Term_ :=
  { toString := fun (e : Term_) => e.toString }

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

declare_syntax_cat symbol_
declare_syntax_cat type_
declare_syntax_cat term_

syntax ident : symbol_

syntax symbol_ : type_
syntax "(" type_ "->" type_ ")" : type_

syntax symbol_ : term_
syntax "(" term_ term_ ")" : term_
syntax "(" "\\" symbol_ "." term_ ")" : term_
syntax "(" term_ ":" type_ ")" : term_
syntax "?" : term_


partial def elabSymbol : Syntax → MetaM Expr
  | `(symbol_| $s:ident) =>
    let s' : Expr := Lean.mkStrLit s.getId.toString
    return s'

  | _ => throwUnsupportedSyntax


partial def elabType : Syntax → MetaM Expr
  -- Var
  | `(type_| $W:symbol_) => do
    let W' : Expr ← elabSymbol W
    mkAppM ``Type_.Var #[W']

  -- Arrow
  | `(type_| ( $T1 -> $T2 )) => do
    let T1' : Expr ← elabType T1
    let T2' : Expr ← elabType T2
    mkAppM ``Type_.Arrow #[T1', T2']

  | _ => throwUnsupportedSyntax


partial def elabTerm : Syntax → MetaM Expr
  -- Var
  | `(term_| $x:symbol_) => do
    let x' : Expr ← elabSymbol x
    mkAppM ``Term_.Var #[x']

  -- App
  | `(term_| ( $e1 $e2 )) => do
    let e1' : Expr ← elabTerm e1
    let e2' : Expr ← elabTerm e2
    mkAppM ``Term_.App #[e1', e2']

  -- Abs
  | `(term_| ( \ $x . $e )) => do
    let x' : Expr ← elabSymbol x
    let e' : Expr ← elabTerm e
    mkAppM ``Term_.Abs #[x', e']

  -- Ann
  | `(term_| ( $e : $T )) => do
    let e' : Expr ← elabTerm e
    let T' : Expr ← elabType T
    mkAppM ``Term_.Ann #[e', T']

  -- Hole
  | `(term_| ?) => do
    let op ← mkAppOptM ``Option.none #[some (.const ``Nat [])]
    mkAppM ``Term_.Hole #[op]

  | _ => throwUnsupportedSyntax


elab "(Symbol_|" s:symbol_ ")" : term => elabSymbol s
elab "(Type_|" T:type_ ")" : term => elabType T
elab "(Term_|" e:term_ ")" : term => elabTerm e

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

mutual
def type_check
  (refine : Bool)
  (goal_table : Std.HashMap Nat Goal_)
  (Gamma : Context_) :
  Term_ → Type_ → Except String (Std.HashMap Nat Goal_)

    -- (-> I)
  | (Term_.Abs x e), T =>
    match T with
    | Type_.Arrow T1 T2 =>
      type_check refine goal_table (Gamma.cons x T1) e T2
    | _ => Except.error "Type checking failed."

  | (Term_.Hole opt), T =>
    match opt with
    | Option.some n =>
      if refine
      then
        let goal_table := goal_table.insert n ⟨ Gamma, T ⟩
        Except.ok goal_table
      else Except.ok goal_table
    | Option.none => Except.ok goal_table

    -- (Turn)
  | e, T =>
    match type_synth refine goal_table Gamma e with
    | Except.ok (goal_table, T') =>
      if T = T'
      then Except.ok goal_table
      else Except.error "Type checking failed."
    | Except.error msg => Except.error s! "Type checking failed. {msg}"


def type_synth
  (refine : Bool)
  (goal_table : Std.HashMap Nat Goal_)
  (Gamma : Context_) :
  Term_ → Except String ((Std.HashMap Nat Goal_) × Type_)

    -- (Var)
  | Term_.Var x =>
    match Gamma.find? x with
    | Option.some T => Except.ok (goal_table, T)
    | Option.none => Except.error "Type synthesis failed."

    -- (-> E)
  | Term_.App e1 e2 =>
    match type_synth refine goal_table Gamma e1 with
    | Except.ok (goal_table, T) =>
      match T with
      | Type_.Arrow T1 T2 =>
        match type_check refine goal_table Gamma e2 T1 with
        | Except.ok goal_table => Except.ok (goal_table, T2)
        | Except.error msg => Except.error s! "Type synthesis failed. {msg}"
      | _ => Except.error "Type synthesis failed."
    | Except.error msg => Except.error s! "Type synthesis failed. {msg}"

    -- (Ann)
  | Term_.Ann e T =>
    match type_check refine goal_table Gamma e T with
    | Except.ok goal_table => Except.ok (goal_table, T)
    | Except.error msg => Except.error s! "Type synthesis failed. {msg}"

  | _ => Except.error s! "Type synthesis failed."
end


def number_holes
  (counter : Nat) :
  Term_ → (Nat × Term_)
  | Term_.Var x => (counter, Term_.Var x)
  | Term_.App e1 e2 =>
    let (counter', e1') := number_holes counter e1
    let (counter'', e2') := number_holes counter' e2
    (counter'', Term_.App e1' e2')
  | Term_.Abs x e =>
    let (counter', e') := number_holes counter e
    (counter', Term_.Abs x e')
  | Term_.Ann e T =>
    let (counter', e') := number_holes counter e
    (counter', Term_.Ann e' T)
  | Term_.Hole opt =>
    match opt with
    | Option.some n => (counter, Term_.Hole (Option.some n))
    | Option.none => (counter + 1, Term_.Hole (Option.some counter))


def replace_hole
  (n : Nat)
  (repl : Term_) :
  Term_ → Term_
  | Term_.Var x => Term_.Var x
  | Term_.App e1 e2 => Term_.App (replace_hole n repl e1) (replace_hole n repl e2)
  | Term_.Abs x e => Term_.Abs x (replace_hole n repl e)
  | Term_.Ann e T => Term_.Ann (replace_hole n repl e) T
  | Term_.Hole opt =>
    match opt with
    | Option.some m =>
      if m = n
      then repl
      else Term_.Hole (Option.some m)
    | Option.none => Term_.Hole Option.none


structure State_ : Type :=
  (goal_table : Std.HashMap Nat Goal_)
  (counter : Nat)
  (current : Term_)

def State_.toString
  (state : State_) :
  String :=
  s! "{state.goal_table.toList}\n{state.current}"

instance : ToString State_ :=
  { toString := fun (state : State_) => state.toString }


-- Attempts to replace the hole numbered n in the current term of the state with the term repl.
def refine
  (state : State_)
  (n : Nat)
  (repl : Term_) :
  Except String State_ :=
  match state.goal_table.get? n with
  | Option.some goal =>
    match type_check false state.goal_table goal.context repl goal.type with
    | Except.ok _ =>
      let (counter, repl) := number_holes state.counter repl
      match type_check true state.goal_table goal.context repl goal.type with
      | Except.ok goal_table =>
        let goal_table := goal_table.erase n
        let refined := replace_hole n repl state.current
        Except.ok ⟨ goal_table, counter, refined ⟩
      | Except.error msg => Except.error s! "Refinement failed. {msg}"
    | Except.error msg => Except.error s! "Refinement failed. {msg}"
  | Option.none => Except.error s! "The term {state.current} does not contain a hole numbered {n}."


def set_goal
  (T : Type_) :
  State_ :=
  ⟨
    Std.HashMap.empty.insert 0 ⟨ AssocList.empty, T ⟩,
    1,
    Term_.Ann (Term_.Hole (Option.some 0)) T
  ⟩


def intro_
  (state : State_)
  (n : Nat)
  (var : Symbol_) :
  Except String State_:=
  refine state n (Term_.Abs var (Term_.Hole Option.none))

def exact_
  (state : State_)
  (n : Nat)
  (e : Term_) :
  Except String State_ :=
  refine state n e


#eval set_goal (Type_| (A -> (B -> A)))

def test := do
  let env := set_goal (Type_| (A -> (B -> A)))
  let env ← intro_ env 0 (Symbol_| x)
  let env ← intro_ env 1 (Symbol_| y)
  let env ← exact_ env 2 (Term_| x)
  return env

#eval test


